# My google app is slow

Tags: google-app-engine

My php app engine is incredibly slow. I am using google drive and the admin sdk in this app. Some pages take 8-10 seconds to load.

This is my app.yaml config for performance:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 2
  max_pending_latency: 1s
```

I am using partial responses for content where ever possible and limiting the number of api calls I make bit its still very slow. Is there anything I'm missing? This is a billed app so that's not likely the issue.

Comment: not enough info. put traces to figure out where it is slow and update the question. min_idle wont help you because its likely the google api calls that slow it down.

Comment: It appears that drive is the bulk of the problem but I am using partial response, querying and only getting a limited number of files so I don't know why it's so slow.

Comment: Yes, Drive api is slow. No appengine configuration will help make ot faster.